# BitmapFactory decodeFile and exif rotation

Tags: android, bitmap

We are finding some inconsistent behaviour among a few android phones.

We using decodeFile to load an image and then rotate it based on  rotation returned by ExifInterface. It's a standard code all overthe stackoverflow and hence not posting here.

On a Samsung phone, the image returned by decodeFile is required to be rotated by the rotation returned by ExifInterface for the correct orientation. Absolutely no issue here for any kind of rotations.

However on some phones, the decodeFile returns the image which is pre-rotated and in the correct orientation although ExifInterface returns some rotation (say 90 or 270). Hence, when we rotate based on the rotation returned by ExifInterface, naturally the final orientation is not correct.

Any idea?

Comment: Also facing the same issue, happening a lot with nexus5

Comment: can you share code you use for decoding image file?